# Relationship of database (MySql) to an engine (InnoDB)?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, storage-engines

There's 10 million articles out there comparing MyISAM to InnoDB (two so-called *database engines*), which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_engine) vaguely defines as:

> "*...the underlying software component that a database management system (DBMS) uses to create, read, update and delete (CRUD) data from a database.*"

But what does that really mean? Surprisingly, I couldn't find a single article talking about the relationship of a DB to its engine!

How does an engine manifest itself in the concrete, real world? Is it that a database is really just a binary file, and that its "engine" is the `.exe` that handles all I/O to and from the file? Does the engine handle `EXPLAIN` AND QEPs?

I guess what I'm asking is: **how do you define which responsibilities are MySQL's, and which activities are the responsibility of its underlying engine?**

Comment: I think the (Storage)Engine (in case of mysql) performs the real operation on the data. Depending on the used engine (MyISAM, InnoDB) you may get better performance for some operations. I heard (== I do not know) that MyIsam is not ACID compliant but very fast for simple writes (e.g. it would be a good consideration for a logging table). I think in general it's better (= safer) to use InnoDB. Other RDBMS do not have this concept (you cannot select the "storage engine").

Comment: A related question on an SO sister site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/what-exactly-is-a-database-engine

Comment: From the manual: *The storage engines themselves are the components of the database server that actually perform actions on the underlying data that is maintained at the physical server level*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this picture help?

[image]

Taken from: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Custom_Engine#Overview

Comment: For me it does, thanks. Together with [this short explanation](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4608) (linked to by Adam Houldsworth) this makes a nice answer.